# Session expired or invalid (Ruby databasedotcom gem)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

I am using salesforce rest api to access the salesforce account from my rails app using databasedotcom gem.I created a remote access app and got the key and the id. I was able to authenticate the user and get the auth_token, instance_url and all that. But, when i send request at

`@client.materialize("Account")`

I get `Session expired or invalid` error

I have developer salesforce account.

please Can anybody help me with this ???

i'm authenticating the user with following request.......

`@client.authenticate :token => token, :instance_url => "http://na1.salesforce.com"`

Comment: Are you sure you're putting in the right value for `token`? It should be a long string beginning with `00D`. Also, make sure the instance is correct -- only asking because `na1` happens to be the instance used in the doc example so wanted to make sure it wasn't just copied and pasted.

Comment: yaah. i corrected the instance it is working now.

Comment: @BhushanLodha Hey Bhushan, Can you give some clarification on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945857/salesforce-error-invalid-cross-reference-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `instance_url` to the instance url that is given.You can get your instance_url from the Oauth2 response. along with the access token it also has the instance_url